# What is the abbreviation for "state"?

Tags: nouns, abbreviations

Obviously, when I go to Google this or search virtually anywhere I get a list of state abbreviations.

But I'm curious, what would the proper way be to abbreviate the actual word *state*?

Comment: You wouldn't abbreviate it.

Comment: @JLG cf. answers below.

Comment: Why do you think there is one? And why do you think there is a "proper" one?

Comment: @ColinFine Why does it matter? It was a label for a user input field in a program where I was limited to using 2 letters... several months ago. I am a programmer, not an English professor. Hence the question.

Comment: In general there isn't a conventional (let alone a 'proper') way to abbreviate an arbitrary word. Your question implied that you thought there was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend either "ST" or "St", without a period (to avoid confusion with the abbreviation for "street"). I live in Washington (the state, not the city), and "Washington St" wouldn't strike me as odd if I read it in a magazine or newspaper. It doesn't look like there's a very rigidly defined standard on this.

But then, NBC seems to like "[Washington St.](http://nbcsports.msnbc.com/id/49405176/ns/sports-college_football/)"

Comment: But isn't a period required in order to indicate that it is an abbreviation? My Oxford Dictionary of Abbreviations lists "st." as an accepted abbreviation for "state".

Comment: Why is that not Washington Street?

Comment: @Henry: Well, it could be. Abbreviations can sometimes introduce ambiguity.

Comment: NY, NY being the classic example.

Comment: I've lived in WA too - Have never encountered Washington St, except when referring to a street. It's just WA, no "st". If you wanted to abbrev might as well go all the way.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was using anyway simply because I needed 2 characters. I could have extended it to a couple more, but the full word is simply too long. I know it's odd request, but sometimes programs need odd things. :)

Answer (score 3):

In the US, the word *state* is generally not abbreviated. When used as parts of acronyms, it is simply referenced as *S*

> NYS (New York State)
>   LSU (Louisiana State University)
>   SUNY (State University of New York)

Use of *ST* or *St* with or without periods is likely to result in confusion with *street*.

Comment: I think your examples are inappropriate/ not relevant: 'State' not as part of an abbreviation, but on its own.

Comment: @Kris In what context would you use *state* as an abbreviation on its own? The only use I can think of is on a form or chart, and in those contexts, three extra letters is a small price to avoid confusion. Maybe in a column to the right of CITY, ST might be acceptable, but probably not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen mailing addresses use "St Hwy" to mean "State Highway"

Consider this possibility...

10152 St Hwy 76

vs

609 South St

"St" can mean State or Street

Answer (score -2):

i would just use St without s period it wouldn't confuse me with St. the period makes me think street no period makes me think state

Comment: Your sentence could do with a period or two.